# How do you serialize a class as its parent class

Tags: inheritance, serialization, attributes

I have two classes ClassA and ClassB. Both have properties and ClassB inherits from ClassA. When I try serialize ClassB into xml i want it to be serialize just like how ClassA would be serialized. Meaning that all the properties that are exclusive to ClassB will be lost and only those inherited from ClassA will be serialized. Is there any way to do this other then marking every property in ClassB with the [XmlIgnoreAttribute] tag?

Edit: ClassA has the [Serializable] tag ClassB does not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `XmlSerializer`, then simply pass `typeof(ClassA)` to its constructor and that should do it.

Comment: This is what i thought, but it is not working the what i want. Thank you for your help.